# Carbon diffforhuman not working on DB raw

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder, php-carbon

This one works fine:

```
$news = NewsFeed::all();
```

return is:

```
{
    "new": [
        {
            "id": "NF_gi042G0493C389rT1z09",
            "user_id": "CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1",
            "newsfeedable_id": "STA_7F5eJ6587n2523750cZr",
            "newsfeedable_type": "Status",
            "created_at": "2015-03-31 06:01:03",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-31 06:01:03"
        },
        {
            "id": "NF_0k625I8vp9sG22637a80",
            "user_id": "CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1",
            "newsfeedable_id": "CNT_dF22v8dorG2k143N1288",
            "newsfeedable_type": "Contact",
            "created_at": "2015-03-30 10:04:34",
            "updated_at": "2015-03-30 10:04:34"
        }
    ]
}
```

==============

But this:

```
$news = DB::select( DB::raw(" SELECT * FROM `news_feed` ") );
```

*note: mysql query is fine, working perfectly*

**My CODE:**

```
$x = $news->updated_at->diffForHumans();
echo $x;
```

ERROR:

> Call to a member function diffForHumans() on a non-object

I did a var_dump here is the result of db raw:

```
{
      "new": [
            {
                "id": "NF_gi042G0493C389rT1z09",
                "user_id": "CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1",
                "newsfeedable_id": "STA_7F5eJ6587n2523750cZr",
                "newsfeedable_type": "Status",
                "created_at": "2015-03-31 06:01:03",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-31 06:01:03"
            },
            {
                "id": "NF_0k625I8vp9sG22637a80",
                "user_id": "CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1",
                "newsfeedable_id": "CNT_dF22v8dorG2k143N1288",
                "newsfeedable_type": "Contact",
                "created_at": "2015-03-30 10:04:34",
                "updated_at": "2015-03-30 10:04:34"
            }
        ]
}
```

Eloquent and DB raw var dump result is 100% the same.

Why is diffForHumans() not working on db raw?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349552/laravel-4-carbon-date-format-change-only-once)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to var_dump the updated_at using eloquent

var_dump($eloquent_news->updated_at);

```
{
        "date": "2015-03-31 06:01:03.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
```

This is the actual result of updated_at render by the eloquent, i don't know how make that happen in DB::raw. But at least you now know what is going on.

**Bottomline:**

> Eloquent updated_at and DB::raw is not 100% the same.